# ASP.NET Data Annotations Regular Expression: Don't allow following characters in Name: \, /, :, *, ;,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

As the title says, I'm looking for a regular expression that don't allow a user to submit the Name with characters : (colon), ; (semicolon), / (forward-slash), \ (backward-slash), * (asterisk) and . (dot)

```
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to black-list just 5 characters? Are you sure that set is complete? Why not white-list characters that you *are* happy for the `Name` to contain?

Comment: It's because I use this name as a part of an imagesrc string when I upload an image file. The server don't allow those characters when you are saving an image file to the server in a directory.

Comment: Then I would *definitely* recommend white-listing a set of characters (say, alphas, numerics + underscore?). I'd definitely be nervous at letting other bits of punctuation through to the file system (such as `?` and `.` which can also, at times, have special meanings)

Comment: So white-list characters means a regular expression that allows certain approved characters?

Comment: Creating a white-list means you create a list of things that you want to allow. Anything not appearing on the list should be rejected. Creating a black-list means you create a list (as in your question) of things that you don't want to allow. Anything appearing on the list is rejected and everything else is allowed. If a white-list is incomplete then you're possibly rejecting some values that may be completely safe. If a black-list is incomplete, then you're letting unsafe values through. It's a lot safer to create a white-list.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how to make this regular expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally ended up with this solution thanks to great suggestions from people on this thread:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\\/:*;\.\)\(]+$", ErrorMessage = "The characters ':', '.' ';', '*', '/' and '\' are not allowed")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Not allowing some special characters -

```
^[^\\/:*;\.\)\(]+$
```

Comment: Works fine, except for the '\' character.

Comment: @Assassin87 You need to escape `\ ` character. Use `^[^\\/:*;]+$`.

Comment: I don't want to allow dots either(.) in the regex.
Everything works except (.) and (\) right now

"^[^\\/:*;]+$"

Comment: @Assassin87, try by escaping those characters also by using `\` . Check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @peramraju.raghavaraju! It works great now with just this minor modification:

@"^[^\\/:*;\.\)\(]+$"

Answer (score 1):

I was checking similar scenario recently but finally created a custom attribute to disallow certain characters. Knew this is old post but posting here so it might help someone.

```
public class RestrictInvalidCharacters : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string DisallowCharacter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RestrictInvalidCharacters"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dCharacters">To get invalid characters.</param>
    public RestrictInvalidCharacters(string dCharacters)
    {
           this.DisallowCharacter = dCharacters;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // converting to generic collection to compare.
        var dChar = this.DisallowCharacter.ToCharArray().ToList();
        string propertyName = validationContext.DisplayName;
           
        // compare if the input string has any disallowed characters
        if (value.ToString().ToCharArray().ToList().Any(x => dChar.Contains(x)))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

using the custom attribute in the property.

```
public class TestClass
{
    [RestrictInvalidCharacters(":;\/*.")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```